# Laravel dynamic controller middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

Hi so I have some routes that are saved in the database each of these has its own controller with its middleware and it is routed via this route;

```
Route::get('{any}', 'RoutingController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

and I try to create the new controller as follows;

```
$container = app();
$route = $container->make(\Illuminate\Routing\Route::class);
$controllerInstance = $container->make($controller);
return (new ControllerDispatcher($container))->dispatch($route, $controllerInstance, $action);
```

So my HomeController has a middleware here;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

However this doesn't get honoured as I'm guessing its not a new request. Is there any way I can honour this middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller dispatcher is not what you want because the middleware is a layer above the controller. You need to run the entire route:

In your `RoutingController`

```
public function index() {
     //Override your route with what it really needs to do
     $route = Route::get(
         {any},
         '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index'
    )->where('any', '.*');
    //Re-handle the request. It should hit your new route.
    app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)->handle(request());
}
```

The idea is you overwrite your general route with what it needs to do based on the request. This should only affect a single request.

Comment: thanks I've added this;              `$route = Route::get(request()->path(),(string)$controllerAction); $route->bind(request());  return $route->run();` and this doesn't run the middleware in the controller for guest. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry that was my bad. Turns out `$route->run` just does what you were doing to begin with. You need `Kernel::handle` in order to go through the entire stack. Try the updated code.

Comment: @apokryfos within this line 
`app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)->handle(request());`
 I have error message 
`Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable` Laravel version 8.  Do you have any ideas please ?

Comment: @dave101ua the app needs to be bootstrapped for that to work i.e. all providers need to have ran. If you still have issues you could try providing your actual Kernel class usually `\App\Http\Kernel`